# Central difference with Convolution

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

So basically I am trying to do finite differencing on a 2d array without doing too many for loops. I would like to have the Hessian matrix of the array and the gradient. So I need both the first-order and second-order derivative of the array.

This can be achieved by evaluating the following equation on the array.
[image]

To deal with boundaries we only compute it for the interior points, so code for this derivate might look something like the following

```py
arr = np.random.rand(16).reshape(4,4)
result = np.zeros_like(arr)
w, h = arr.shape
for i in range(1, w-1):
    for j in range(1, h-1):
        result[i,j] = (arr[i+1, j] - arr[i-1, j]) / (2*dx)
```

This gives the correct answer but can be very slow compared to numpy operations, so I thought to myself. This is basically just a convolution with a kernel that looks like this

```
kernel = [1, 0, -1]
```

So we execute the following code

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve
result = np.pad((convolve(arr,kernel,mode='same', 
             method = 'direct')/(2*dx))[1:-1, 1:-1], 1).T
```

Since we are only dealing with the interior points, we cut them off and pad them with zeros afterward, to mimic what would happen in the previous naive case.

This works! But with some arrays, the mean squared error between the naive case and the convolution case skyrockets. So it seems that the numerical error increases very much for some cases.

I would like the speed gained by convolution with the stability of the naive case. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply slice and operate. Hence, after output initialization, do -

```
result[1:-1,1:-1] = (arr[2:,1:-1] - arr[:-2,1:-1])/(2*dx)
```

Convolution IMHO would be an overkill when working with NumPy arrays, as slicing arrays are virtually free on memory and performance. Being compute heavy, one can look into `numexpr` though to leverage multi-cores.